# how to create a list of pdf page numbers if pdf page contains specific text strings using python

Tags: python, pdf

I am trying to extract PDF page numbers if the page contains certain strings, and then append the selected page numbers to a list. For example, page 2, 254, 439 and 458 meet the criteria and I'm expecting the output as a list [2,254,439,458]. My code is:

```
object=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file_path)
NumPages = object.getNumPages()
String = 'specific string'
for i in range(0,NumPages):
  PageObj=object.getPage(i)
  Text = PageObj.extractText()
  ReSearch = re.search(String,Text)
  Pagelist=[]
  if ReSearch != None:
     Pagelist.append(i)
     print(Pagelist)
```

I received output as:

- [2]
- [254]
- [439]
- [458]

Could someone please take a look and see how I can fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are defining a new llst in every iteration, so you have to define the list only once, before the loop. Also print it outside the loop:

```
Pagelist=[]
for i in range(0,NumPages):
    # rest of the loop
print(Pagelist)
```

Comment: Thank you @TDG! Do you know what is the solution for extracting text when the pdf file has watermark? In this case, the code below doesn't return a list of page number for some files even though they contain the specific string, because they have the watermark "client copy".  Thanks.

Comment: I really don't know, I think you should ask a new question about it.